# Proper way to configure a persistent H2 database

Tags: spring-boot, h2

I'm following [this Spring Boot tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/) that uses an H2 database and I was wondering what was the correct way to set up an H2 database so that:

- It creates itself at the first launch of the application
- It keeps the data between different launches

I'm currently using the following in my application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/somefile
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Is it the correct way? H2 needs to be in "file" mode for that, right? (I assume it can't be done with the in-memory mode?)

Answer (score 0):

I am using H2 database where schema and data has been created by two separate files  - schema.sql and data.sql

schema.sql -

```
CREATE TABLE METADATA(
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
NAME VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
);
```

data.sql -

```
 INSERT INTO METADATA(ID,NAME) values (1,'John');
```

and rest of the h2, hibernate and jpa configuration in application.yaml file

```
 server:
   port: 8080

 spring:
   h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
      path: /h2-console
      settings.trace: false
      settings.web-allow-others: false
    datasource:
      url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
      driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
      username: sa
      password: 
   jpa:
     database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
     show-sql: true
     defer-datasource-initialization: true
     hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
   sql:
     init:
      mode: always
      data-location: classpath:data.sql
 logging:
   level:
     org.hibernate.SQL: INFO
     org.hibernate.type: INFO
     com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig: DEBUG
     com.zaxxer.hikari: TRACE
```

You can check by login into h2-console and see the database using - http://localhost:8080/h2-console using the and see the schema

[image]